# Time complexity for displaying generic tree and finding total number of nodes in it

Tags: data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I am having some difficulty in understanding the time complexity for displaying generic tree and finding total number of nodes in it .
I have looked for some articles online , there are articles on what a generic tree is but there is not much on time complexity for generic tree . I previously thought that it will be O(N) for finding total number of nodes and O(N) for displaying all the nodes(displaying data of the nodes) but one comment on the video from which I was studying generic trees says that its O(N) for displaying all the nodes of tree and O(N^N) for finding total number of nodes in it where 'N' is total number of nodes . Can someone help me out ?

Comment: I don't see how counting could have bigger complexity than printing...

Comment: That comment seams wrong, N^N seams too high

Comment: so its O(N) for both cases right ?

Comment: That is what I would say so. But do not go to another site, saying that you saw a comment in SO saying that it was O(N) because I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting all nodes of a finite generic tree is O(N), no matter whether you take a depth-first or breadth-first approach. So counting the number of nodes is also O(N), and O(1) if counts are stored in the nodes.

Printing all nodes is O(N) only if printing a single node is O(1). That's not generally the case. If the N nodes of the tree contain the numbers 1...N, for example, the complexity for printing the node values (in binary or decimal) would be O(N log N).

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail the case when printing is O(N log N)?

Comment: @Lak An integer `n` written in base `b` has length `log_b(n)`, hence printing `n` takes `O(log n)` time. Printing 1, 2, 3, ..., `n` takes `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n) = log(n!)`, which is `O(n log n)`.